# AWS Cognito sign user in without username and password from server

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

Is it possible for my server to get credentials for a user without their username and password in order to send it back to the client?

I have another means of authentication and I think this would be easier to do this rather than trying to store tokens in a database where they will expire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You can provide alternatives to Username/Password to login a user. [Developer Authenticated Identities Authflow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html) let your server take the place of the user pool or other social identity provider.

User Pools are just that, an AWS hosted authentication tool. They let users prove they own a specific login string (email, phone, etc.) by providing a password. Then that user is mapped to an Identity in an Identity Pool.

You can also use Facebook as the "proof" and get an Identity ID that way. If you pass both (User pool and Facebook) tokens to the Identity pool at the same time you will link those two login ID under one Identity ID. Now you can log in using either method and the app will treat you as the same person because you have the same Identity ID.

You can implement a server which will let you act as that same type of provider so that users can prove to your server they are who they say they are then you can signal to the Identity pool that they are "X" person.

The thing to remember is that the User pool is used to store and validate username/password combos (and some other attributes if you want). The Identity pool is used to map 1 or more logins (Facebook, Google, User Pool, etc) to an Identity Id that your app(s) can use to identify/differentiate users.

Comment: Yes! this was really starring in my face the whole time... it seems obvious now. Thanks

Comment: Just to confirm... I should only return an IdToken from my service right? and if I pass that as a Login value to AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials when fetching my session, Cognito will take care of everything else (AccessToken, RefreshToken, etc)?

Comment: @ovg Yes. Here is the docs on setting up the [token generation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html#getting-a-token-server-side) on your server.

Answer (score 0):

No you would have to either, at least authenticate once with Cognito (afterwards use refresh tokens to obtain new id/access tokens without having to enter username/password) or federate with another Identity Provider (but you would still have to authenticate with that identity provider).

Comment: So are you saying for my case I should store that refresh token in a database myself? Does this refresh token expire? Does it need to be updated? What do I do with it on the client side?